# Maven error during the compilation in netbeans

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, maven-plugin, netbeans-8

When i was executing my first java app in netbeans, i was asked to install something related to maven and the installation failed on it's own.

"Run project (F6)":

```
cd /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /opt/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn "-Dexec.args=-classpath %classpath edu.sora.lab2.Lab2_Pavlenko_KI33" -Dexec.executable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec
Running NetBeans Compile On Save execution. Phase execution is skipped and output directories of dependency projects (with Compile on Save turned on) will be used instead of their jar artifacts.
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Lab2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- exec-maven-plugin:1.5.0:exec (default-cli) @ Lab2 ---
??????? ?????? ?????????? ???????:
```

---

"Clean and build (SHIFT + F11)" SUCCESS!!!
(WHY "Run project (F6)" works badly??? I'm confused):

```
cd /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64 /opt/netbeans/java/maven/bin/mvn -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 clean install
Scanning for projects...

------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building Lab2 1.0-SNAPSHOT
------------------------------------------------------------------------

--- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Lab2 ---
Deleting /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2/target

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Lab2 ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2/src/main/resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ Lab2 ---
Changes detected - recompiling the module!
Compiling 1 source file to /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2/target/classes

--- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Lab2 ---
Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
skip non existing resourceDirectory /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2/src/test/resources

--- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Lab2 ---
Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date

--- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Lab2 ---
No tests to run.

--- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ Lab2 ---
Building jar: /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2/target/Lab2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

--- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Lab2 ---
Installing /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2/target/Lab2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar to /home/sagecat/.m2/repository/edu/sora/Lab2/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Lab2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Installing /home/sagecat/Documents/Study/Cross-platform_programming_tools/working_directory/Lab2/Lab2/pom.xml to /home/sagecat/.m2/repository/edu/sora/Lab2/1.0-SNAPSHOT/Lab2-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 1.128 s
Finished at: 2020-04-17T14:02:44+03:00
Final Memory: 13M/50M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Maybe useful info:

[image: problem]

Available plugins for a "maven" search:

[image: search]

Installed plugins:
[image: installed]

All available plugins in java* categories:

[image: all]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**

I don't know what, actually, helped... Sorry =(

I tried everything and installed many things and also reinstalled all maven packages using synaptic. And the next time i tried - it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install maven plugin in netbeans. To do so go to Tools -> Plugins.
In the available plugin sections,Select the Maven Plugin for JAVA. Install it and must activate it.
[This Plugin is must](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU21G.png)

[If this is not available in Available plugin List then check in other tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFNjv.png)

Comment: There is no such a plugin to select. It was a "Maven runner" and i've installed it, but nothing changed.

Comment: Please check if Maven tab is available in your workspace by navigating to this-> Tools->Options....

Comment: If its available then you need to set the Maven Home pointing to your maven binaries

Comment: Maven tab Tools->Options->Java->Maven is available. I need to set Maven->Experimental->(Use the following location to store Maven binaries), am i? If it so, how can i find Maven binaries dir?

Comment: Nothing changed(((